# Show context in R debugger?

Tags: r, debugging

If I've dropped into the R debugger by using `options(error=recover)`, how can I get my bearings and see the code around where it's dropped me?  For example:

```
options(error=recover)
solve(matrix(0, nrow=5, ncol=5))

# Error in solve.default(matrix(0, nrow = 5, ncol = 5)) : 
#   Lapack routine dgesv: system is exactly singular: U[1,1] = 0
# 
# Enter a frame number, or 0 to exit   
# 
# 1: solve(matrix(0, nrow = 5, ncol = 5))
# 2: solve.default(matrix(0, nrow = 5, ncol = 5))
# 
# Selection: 1
# Called from: top level 
Browse[1]>
```

At this point if I hit <kbd>n</kbd> or <kbd>return</kbd>, I just die again and get the `recover` prompt, without ever seeing any lines of code.  If I do a stack trace (type `where`), I can see the call chain, but not the code I'm actually sitting in (at any level of the stack).  *[Actually I do see a bit of code in this `solve` case, but only because one anonymous function is part of the stack so it has no choice but to print its definition rather than its name.]*

Any tips?

[EDIT] I'm interested (among others) in the use case where I need to figure out what's going on in someone's package code.  I don't control the source, so I can't add a `browser()`, and I don't have easy access to the source file, so just a line number wouldn't be much help.  I'd mainly just want to see the actual code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you like Emacs, I understand that the ess-tracebug package provides this function by moving a cursor to the current line in a source code buffer. ess-tracebug is included in the latest version of ESS mode.

(If the OP doesn't like Emacs, don't vote up my answer: please wait for a better one.)

Comment: In fact, I do like Emacs. =)

Comment: Looks like I'm going to need some more time to figure out how to get ess-tracebug to work, but it looks great.  I already use ESS.

Answer (score 5):

If you also set `options(show.error.locations=TRUE)`, R will print the source line number with the error, e.g.

```
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) (from test.R#4) :
```

`test.R` would be the name of your script, and #4 indicates the error occurred on line four.

If you're just using `browser` to insert a breakpoint, you can supply some identifying text with `browser(text='end of plotting function')`, and then retrieve this text when you are in the browsing session with `browserText()` to verify where you are.

#### EDIT

If you want to find the location of an error encountered when using an installed function, the standard way is to call `debug` on the function, run your code, then step through until you encounter the error. See `?debug` for more details.

If you're the impatient type, however, you could use the following trick to get the line number of the installed function's body where the error occurred when `show.error.locations` is set to `TRUE`.

```
s<-paste(c(capture.output(dump('solve.default', file='')), 
          'solve(matrix(0, nrow=5, ncol=5))'), 
         collapse='\n')
source(textConnection(s))
```

Here `s` is a string comprised of the definition of `solve.default` (the method that gets called on your matrix in the example you provided), and the call that raises the error.

Comment: Handy, I didn't know that.  But it doesn't actually seem to do anything in this case, the output for the `solve` error looks the same to me.

Comment: If you're trying this directly in the R terminal, there's not going to be a source line number of course. I don't believe this option was added until 2.15, it might be your version.

Comment: Why wouldn't there be any line-number information for the `solve` function?  I'm running in R version 2.15.2, you mean you get different results?

Comment: `show.error.locations` shows the line number of an error encountered while executing source code, not the code of functions that are already installed. You can use the `debug` function, e.g., `debug(solve)` to step through an installed function until you encounter the error.